# How to use choirs in epic music

Tags: midi, voice, orchestra

I'm relatively new to MIDI orchestration and would like to start using choirs and vocals in my tracks. I understand using them to emphasize hits and climaxes, but I would like to imitate songs like "Ocean Princess" by Thomas Bergson - using vocals as part of the, or the main - melody. Also, what language is it usually in? I've looked at Latin, but the syllables sound a little rough when sung. Suggestions? Techniques? Resource?

Comment: If you can't tell what language it is in, why does it matter? Sometimes these are in Latin, sometimes in other Romanic languages, and sometimes in nonsense or fictitious languages.

Comment: There are no shortcuts.  You have to actually learn how to write music.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are likely to end up happy with MIDI choirs and vocals.  Human hearing is tuned to human voice use.  Faking instruments (which are sort of an abstraction of voice) is much likely to end up with something that serves a similar purpose.